# Composer package is updated, but core still asks to update

Tags: updating, composer

I am using Drupal 8.5.5. On admin/modules/update I red the following message.

[Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) (Theme)
Bootstrap (Theme) 8.x-3.11 update to 8.x-3.12 (Release notes)

The composer.json contains the following text.

```
"require": {
    ...
    "drush/drush": "^9.3",
    "drupal/core": "~8.5.3",
    "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.12" 
},
```

I then ran `composer install` and installed Bootstrap 8.x-3.12. When I run `composer show drupal/bootstrap` it outputs the following.

```
name     : drupal/bootstrap
descrip. : Built to use Bootstrap, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful front- 
end framework for faster and easier web development.
keywords :
versions : * 3.12.0 
type     : drupal-theme
license  : GNU General Public License v2.0 only (GPL-2.0) (OSI approved) 
https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-2.0.html#licenseText
source   : [git] https://git.drupal.org/project/bootstrap 8.x-3.12
dist     : [zip] https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/bootstrap-8.x-3.12.zip 8.x-3.12
names    : drupal/bootstrap

requires
drupal/core ~8.0
```

When I go back to admin/modules/update Drupal still says Bootstrap 8.x-3.11 is installed. I have ran `drush updb` and `drush cr` to no avail. I am confused as to why it is not running composer's version of Bootstrap.

Why?

EDIT:
When I run `drush pm:list --package bootstrap` the command line returns:

`Bootstrap (bootstrap)  Enabled    8.x-3.11` . Yet composer's version is on 8.x-3.12.

Comment: Hmm.  Drush is using the actual info.yml file for bootstrap, so what is on the disk is that version.  Maybe something is marked r/o or composer is installing it someplace else.

Comment: @CGMonroe You helped me find my solution. In my composer.json file, "installer-paths": {
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
but my drush theme was located in sites/default/theme/bootstrap. Need to do some configuration management and should work! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CREDIT TO @CGMonroe**

I had started since early stages of Drupal 8, so my themes folder was in

```
sites/default/theme/bootstrap
sites/default/theme/bootstrap_subtheme
```

but in composer.json, it updates in directory:

```
"installer-paths": {
  ...
  "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
```

so what I needed to do was, move my /bootstrap_subtheme from sites/default/theme to theme/
you should end up with:

```
theme/contrib/bootstrap
theme/custom/bootstrap_subtheme
```

and here is the correct way of configuring a theme/subtheme: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-a-drupal-8-sub-theme-or-sub-theme-of-sub-theme